# Action sheet loads for 1st time with an space from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: iphone

Action Sheet shows an space of height 20 to 30 pixels when the action sheet loads for the 1st time. When I load the action sheet for the second time it loads properly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES]; 
    [self loadImage:nil]; 
}
```

When the view load, I am calling the above event which is showing the space at the bottom of the page.

And when I load it from the following function it is working fine.

```
- (IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender { 
    if(!actionSheetAction) { 
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                                 delegate:self 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"     
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Use Photo from Library", 
                                                                          @"Take Photo with Camera", nil]; 
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault; 
        actionSheetAction = ActionSheetToSelectTypeOfSource; 
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 
        [actionSheet release]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];
 [self loadImage:nil];

}
When the view load i am calling the above event which is showing the space at the bottom of the page.

Comment: and when  i load it from the  following function it is working fine...
- (IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender {
 if(!actionSheetAction) {
  UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
              otherButtonTitles:@"Use Photo from Library", @"Take Photo with Camera", nil];
  actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
  actionSheetAction = ActionSheetToSelectTypeOfSource;
  [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
  [actionSheet release];
 }
}

Comment: next time please add the code to the question. nobody wants to read code in a comment.

Comment: ok dude it not an issue i had to solve the issue at the 1st place in an hurry i have done that..

Comment: It looks like code required to understand this question was added to comments, and was not added to the question. That means the question is lacking a [mcve], and needs to be put on hold until it can be repaired. I will try to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

When you set UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque style of status bar or Navigationbar style with opaque(dont know it's name exactly) then your view will start from Y zero means it's origin Y=0 in case of other style of status bar without opaque Y will be Y=20. May be this will help you.And in case of navigation bar style without opaque you'r origin Y will be 44 and if you have set any Navigation bar type with Opaque then YOur Y will 0(Y=0).
Thanks.

Comment: before viewdid load i think style will be other than blackOpaque right?